# ROW_NUMBER vs COUNT(1)?

Tags: sql-server, count, window-functions, row-number

Which of the two alternatives is better?

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)
```

or

```
COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)
```

I could not find any such question.

**Edit:**

```
DBMS: SQL-SERVER (version >= 2008)
```

In my case the over partition is guaranteed by a single field:
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ELEMENT ORDER BY EMPLOYEE)
COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ELEMENT ORDER BY EMPLOYEE)

ELEMENT      EMPLOYEE       ROW_NUMBER       COUNT
0000001      00000003       1                1
0000001      00000004       2                2
0000001      00000005       3                3
0000003      00000045       1                1
0000003      00000046       2                2

Comment: Those two are doing two different things

Comment: The only thing vaguely relevant to this is `SUM(1)` vs. `COUNT(*)`. `ROW_NUMBER()` can be written in terms of `COUNT(*)`, but not like this, not efficiently, and there's no reason to do so in the first place unless you're still stuck with SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @JeroenMostert: how do you know Daniele is using SQL Server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't, and fortunately in this case my comment is not contingent on it. People who are not using SQL Server are not stuck with SQL Server 2000, by definition. :-)

Comment: sorry for my few information, I modified information in question

Comment: "*I wanted to know, which of two solutions is the most performing on equal terms.*" This comparison really got nothing to do with performance. The results of the 2 options cannot guaranteed to be the same. So any performance differential is due to the inherent functional differences and you should choose the technique that meets the functional need. If you wanted a more reasonable comparison it would be to `sum(1) over(...)` as has been mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 5):

`COUNT(1)` behaves different when the same group of values in the `ORDER BY` columns are repeated.

The following is an example of SQL Server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Example') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Example

CREATE TABLE #Example (
    Number INT,
    GroupNumber INT)

INSERT INTO #Example (
    Number,
    GroupNumber)
VALUES
    (NULL, 1),
    (100, 1),
    (101, 1),
    (102, 1),
    (103, 1),

    (NULL, 2),
    (NULL, 2),
    (NULL, 2),
    (200, 2),
    (201, 2),
    (202, 2),

    (300, 3),
    (301, 3),
    (301, 3),
    (301, 3),
    (302, 3)


SELECT
    E.*,
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.GroupNumber ORDER BY E.Number ASC),
    CountOver = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY E.GroupNumber ORDER BY E.Number ASC)
FROM
    #Example AS E
```

Result:

```
Number      GroupNumber RowNumber            CountOver
----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
NULL        1           1                    1
100         1           2                    2
101         1           3                    3
102         1           4                    4
103         1           5                    5

NULL        2           1                    3 Here
NULL        2           2                    3
NULL        2           3                    3
200         2           4                    4
201         2           5                    5
202         2           6                    6

300         3           1                    1
301         3           2                    4 Here
301         3           3                    4
301         3           4                    4
302         3           5                    5
```

This is because it's a count and not a row number. You should use the one that's appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Hi Ezequiel, your answer it's right on the basis your example; in my case the value of field in ORDER BY it's never NULL

Comment: It's not just for NULLs, repeated values also will increase the count (see values 301 in my example). If your data ensures that no repeated values occur, then the result will always be the same for both, but it might be more expensive to the engine to do the count than the row number, although I doubt we will be able to notice the performance difference between the two.

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to know,  which of two solutions is the most performing on equal terms. Many thanks Ezequiel.